# How to Create Mobile-friendly Responsive Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am new in HTML, CSS and i am trying to make simple responsive menu.After resize the browser menu icon will display and then will click to open menu and.Please check below code.Would you help me in this?
Note:I don't want to use bootstrap.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu-bar
{
 
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.menu-logo
{
  float: left;
}

nav{
  width: 100%;text-align: center;

}
nav ul
{
background-color: #A4D54C;
float: right;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 50px;

}
nav  li{


display: inline;
list-style-type: none;

}

nav  a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.menu-logo
{
  margin-top: -50px;
}

 nav 
  {
   
  }
nav ul{
  float: none;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #A4D54C;


}

nav  li{
  display: inline;
}
nav  a{
  color: #fff;
}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #menu-bar
  {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-logo
{
  width: 100%;text-align: center;
}


 nav 
  {
   
  }

nav  ul{
  float: none;
margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: #A4D54C;
}

nav  li{
}

nav  a{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 03px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="menu-logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>

    <div style="text-align:right">
      <span> info@info.com</span> 
    </div>

<nav>
  <span id="menu-bar"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </nav>
```

Comment: Any one help me in this?

Comment: try to give `nav ul`  `float :left` and `nav li` to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Should i add  above code in media query?

Comment: yes.. check if it works or not.

Comment: Sorry! its not working.All menu showing in one row

Comment: What's is style you like? Do you like hamburger menu?

Comment: I have to create simple menu..

Comment: menu will open form top to bottom like that or any easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For responsive menu we start window screen from 768Px so I don't change any thing on your css just replace the media screen 400px with 768px and remove the media section you created for 768px. I also comment out in all 3 section HTML, CSS and jQuery where I change or add with a short description. Any Question ask me in comment. Thank you. [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/fvssbgo0/6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-bar').click(function() {

    $("nav ul").slideToggle("slow"); /* this function show/hide the menu when you click the bar icon */
  })
  $('nav ul li  a').click(function() {
    $('nav  ul ').slideToggle("slow"); /* this function hide the menu when you click on a link*/
  })

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu-bar {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.menu-logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: #A4D54C;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-bar {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* set this margin because its close to the window screen*/
  }
  .menu-logo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav {}
  nav ul {
    float: none;
    display: none;
    /* set display none for use the click fucntion to show the menu*/
    background-color: #A4D54C;
 /* Set margin and padding 0 for full width border bottom*/
    margin:0;
   padding: 0;  
  }
  nav li {}
  nav a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="menu-logo"><img class="logo-img" src="#"></div>

<div style="text-align:right;margin-right:10px;">
  <!-- set this margin-right 10px because its close to the window screen -->
  <span> info@info.com</span>
</div>

<nav>
  <span id="menu-bar"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--add href="#" to see the jQuery click function is working or not -->
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: @NarendraVerma Can you explain a little bit. which left side border ??

Comment: Code updated added  {margin:0; padding: 0; } to nav ul inside media query. I also comment out where I added those lines. You can also check fiddle  [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/fvssbgo0/4/  ]

Comment: Mr.Mostafa Baezid. I think there must be some issue in your script because when i clicked on menu link it closing and i clicked on second time of any menu it's not closing.

Comment: Oops sorry maybe I remove the prevent function let me check

Comment: I will wait for your reply

Comment: Error was small I set #menu-bar click function close tag  after the 'a' click function. So it get into a loop. So you happy with the answer ??

Comment: Yes i am happy with your code and your support..Appreciate for your support..thank you very much Mr.Mostafa

Comment: Mr.Mostafa can you help me in this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754112/how-to-display-session-value-on-sweet-alert-popup?noredirect=1#comment66808026_39754112

Comment: Let me check on that. Never work on sweet alert before.. let me check on that. Will give you a answer soon .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124517/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-mostafa-baezid).

Answer (score 1):

Try Bootstrap framework

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="hidden-xs">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Home</a>
        </li>
                <li>
        <a href="#products" class="hidden-xs">Products</a>
        <a href="#products" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#overview" class="hidden-xs">Overview</a>
        <a href="#overview" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Overview</a>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/84mqazgq/

Comment: I agree with using a "hamburger" menu. You don't necessarily need a front end framework like Bootstrap to achieve this, although it does make it easier.

Comment: Thanks for replay Mr.Dolphine....Is there any way to make menu without bootstrap?I want to use only HTML CSS and for clickable will use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can write Media Query for it. if you don't want to use bootstrap.

eg.

you want to make a webpage to be responsive for 768px, then you can write .

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        // Your CSS Code Here
    }
}
```

For reference You can see [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Bhavin, I tried in media query but getting issue so that i uploaded code in question.Please check my code and assist me where i am wrong.

Comment: try to give `nav ul`  `float :left` and `nav li` to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :)
This work for me. and without bootstrap

```js
$('#menu-bar').click(function(){
$('nav ul').toggle('blind');
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu-bar
{
 
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #A4D54C;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:-50px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.menu-logo
{
  float: left;
  
}

nav{
  width: 100%;text-align: center;

}
nav ul
{
background-color: #A4D54C;
float: right;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 50px;

}
nav  li{


display: inline;
list-style-type: none;

}

nav  a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.menu-logo
{
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#menu-bar {
  display:block;
}
 nav 
  {
   
  }
nav ul{
  float: none;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #A4D54C;
display:none;

}

nav  li{
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
nav  a{
  color: #fff;
}
  
  
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #menu-bar
  {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-logo
{
  width: 100%;text-align: center;
}


 nav 
  {
   
  }

nav  ul{
  float: none;
margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: #A4D54C;
}

nav  li{
  
}

nav  a{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 03px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="menu-logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>

    <div style="text-align:right">
      <span> info@info.com</span> 
    </div>

<nav>
  <span id="menu-bar"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </nav>
```

Comment: This ans is useful. My 80% issue got resolved.Thanks Mr.Habib.......I have doubt why my border-bottom not showing 100%.I tried code in midia query nav  li{
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
} right side is ok but left side not good

Comment: Ok. nope, you're welcome 
I change minor CSS code in your style, but this is just for make it cleaner. You could change again if you needed. 
Do you would click tick button on the left my answer, so other users know the right answer.

Comment: I have updated the code. try and look! Now the `nav li` is showing `border-bottom`

Comment: Sorry Mr.Habib Rohman.If you can  check Mr.Mostafa Baezid output and your output.Mr.Mostafa Baezid code is help me in this yesterday.