# How to display full content on background image in mobile device?

Tags: css, html

I am able to display content on image in desktop but when i am resizing my browser my content not showing properly.
So issue is how to set background image with full content?Please check my below images you will get idea what i am asking?
My background image height is 500px.
Would you help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

```css
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

p{
  color: red;
}
.test-1
{
  background-image:url('images/images-bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  background-position: center;

}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="test-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>

        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**In Desktop** There is no issue in this
[image]

**After resizing**

[image]

Comment: use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit the CSS, and add `background-size`

```
.test-1 {
  background-image:url('images/images-bg.png');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  background-position: center;
}
```

You can read more about `background-size` in [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: trust me Mr.Habib Rohan , I tried background-size:cover; and that time it didn't worked.......Thanks for help me in this...It working now.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to clear your cache and cookies. 
Actually you can change `cover` to `contain` or `100% 100%` anything what you want todo but I recomended to this question is using `cover`. finally, do you want to click tick button left my answer. so other user know the right answer.

Comment: Mr.Habib can you help me in below link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740988/how-to-create-mobile-friendly-responsive-menu?noredirect=1#comment66791607_39740988

Answer (score 0):

remove the width 100% and set background-size: cover and also remove the html, body section. Your using bootstrap so you don't need to define that

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

.test-1 {
  background: url(http://www.hollanders.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/i/sil370523644_1_2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="test-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat est eget tempor ornare. Fusce malesuada magna non nisl efficitur tempor. Nam mattis ullamcorper ante ut iaculis. Proin ornare, neque eu pulvinar sodales, tortor lacus blandit diam, eu feugiat nisl dolor eget urna. Morbi quis tellus ultrices, condimentum ex vel, rhoncus nisi. Vivamus vestibulum quam sem, ac finibus mauris blandit ut. Pellentesque convallis massa id consectetur faucibus. Donec ac mi ac ante commodo convallis quis quis risus. Ut orci nisl, sodales non consectetur blandit, interdum rutrum mauris. Fusce ullamcorper in lorem at cursus. Mauris congue tristique orci quis suscipit.</p>

        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Mostafa.I got solution now.

Comment: Mr.Mostafa can you help me in below link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740988/how-to-create-mobile-friendly-responsive-menu?noredirect=1#comment66791607_39740988

Comment: @Hybreeder I can help you. But one question is can I change the structure? Maybe I will provide you a better navigation which is responsive and with looks good too.